# ExtJS: How to waiting for Promise response in initComponent method?

Tags: javascript, extjs, promise, containers, response

I've implemented a `initComponent` method to `Container` class and loading `items` config through a `Promise` method.

The thing during `debugging` firstly goes to `callParent` line and then executes goes to `Promise` method.. I've to reload the browser to be able fetching `Promise` response.

I've tried `then()` method in `initComponent` but gives error. How can I achieve to this usage?

**- Container class with `initComponent`;**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Bar', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'barview',
    requires: [],
    controller: 'barctrl',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'barvm'
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        let me = this;
        let fooInfo = MyApp.FooInfoClass.getFooInfo(); //There is a debugger in FooInfoClass but miss this one

        if (fooInfo) {
            if (fooInfo.self) {
                me.items = [
                    {
                        xtype: 'componentA'
                    }
                ];
            } else if (fooInfo.reference) {
                me.items = [
                    {
                        xtype: 'componentB'
                    }
                ];
            } else {
                me.items = [
                    {
                        xtype: 'componentC'
                    }
                ];
            }
        }

        debugger //Firstly comes to this one then goes to Promise 
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**- Promise class and method;**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.FooInfoClass', {
    requires: [],
    singleton: true,
    endpoint: MyApp.Url(),

    getFooInfo: function () {
        let me = this;
        let responseInfo = localStorage.getItem('foo-info');

        return JSON.parse(responseInfo);
    },

    setFooInfo: function (foo) {
        let me = this;

        me.foo = JSON.stringify(foo);
        localStorage.setItem(me.fooInfo, me.foo);
    },

    fooInfo: function () {
        let me = this;

        return new Ext.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: me.endpoint + '/info',

                success: function(response, opts) {
                    let obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    let data = obj.data[0];
                    debugger //Secondly comes to here!
                    me.foo = data;
                    me.setFooInfo(me.foo);
                    resolve(me.foo);
                },

                failure: function(response, opts) {
                    console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response);
                    reject(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not defer finishing the `initComponent` function until you have the data you need. Either you fetch the data first and instantiate the component once all your required info together (do the `Ext.create()` inside `Promise.then()`), or you let the component get its required info and add the child components *at runtime* based on these infos. There are only very very few things that you really *have* to know before calling `callParent` on `initComponent`.

If I were you, instead of using `me.items =` , I would just use `me.add()` so that adding the child components will happen at runtime, after initialization.

I have made a simple fiddle for you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k9r

Comment: `me.add` did not work for me as expected but whole I got your idea  and now my usage is more robust. Thanks.